# Blazor Identity show manage user profile pages within an existing page

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity

I added the Identity to my existing Blazor App using scaffolding.

I've created my own drop-down control to allow users to access their profile or logout, which redirects to the corresponding pages

```
async Task OnMyProfileClick() {
    await Task.Delay(0);
    Navigation.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Manage/", true);
}
```

Profile opens fine - but it is loaded in a fully new page, so not applying my desired layout (which has a header and a navigation bar) - I'd like to keep the main layout showing and display the actual Manage page within the MainLayout's `@body` instead of a new page.

Is this possible out of the box, or should I transform all existing pages to razor components?

Comment: how are you displaying your identity page in blazor? is it just razor pages?

Comment: It's the default scaffolded `*.cshtml` pages location in `Areas/Identity/*`

Comment: this is because razor pages are inheriting the layout from pages/shared/_layout.cshtml

Comment: so I should override `pages/shared/_layout.cshtml` content with `/shared/_layout.cshtml`?

Comment: May I suggest this issue? [Styling Identity Razor Pages to use default Blazor theme](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45174)

Comment: Great link thx. One thing though - what if my MainPage.razor contains code I'd like to add to the Layout.cshtm?